# How to call mousewheel.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I am a little unsure how to properly call this plugin [mousewheel.js](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel)

I'm using it in conjunction with [jscrollplane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to make a custom scroll bar.

I call jscrollplane using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.scroll-pane').each(
        function()
        {
            $(this).jScrollPane(
                {
                    showArrows: $(this).is('.arrow')
                }
            );
            var api = $(this).data('jsp');
            var throttleTimeout;
            $(window).bind(
                'resize',
                function()
                {
                    if ($.browser.msie) {
                        if (!throttleTimeout) {
                            throttleTimeout = setTimeout(
                                function()
                                {
                                    api.reinitialise();
                                    throttleTimeout = null;
                                },
                                50
                            );
                        }
                    } else {
                        api.reinitialise();
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    )

    })
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

And the following for mousewheel.js

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    (function ($) {
       $('.scroll-pane')
                    .mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
                        var o = '';
                        if (delta > 0)
                            o = '.scroll-pane: up ('+delta+')';
                        else if (delta < 0)
                            o = '.scroll-pane: down ('+delta+')';

                        if (deltaX > 0)
                            o = o + ', east ('+deltaX+')';
                        else if (deltaX < 0)
                            o = o + ', west ('+deltaX+')';

                        if (deltaY > 0)
                            o = o + ', north ('+deltaY+')';
                        else if (deltaY < 0)
                            o = o + ', south ('+deltaY+')';

                        if( o != '' )
                            log( o );
                        return false; // prevent default
                    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

jscrollplane works fine, just not mousewheel.

Comment: what browser did you use? did you try another browser?
also what the version of your jquery

Comment: It doesn't seem to work properly in any browser. Tested with Mozilla, Chrome, and IE

Comment: Did you put the mousewheel code at the bottom of the page?  You don't have the jquery.ready function on that like you do the scrollpane code.

Comment: I added in the document ready, wasn't sure if it was needed. The code still doesn't seem to e working properly. I'll keep looking.

Comment: what's your jquery version? i had the same issue

Comment: Using 1.6.2 at the moment. (What my server currently has on it)